# Why not use an extended rational instead of floats/doubles?

Tags: floating-point

### Why not use extended rationals for floating point representations?

The idea is that computers are discrete, such that true irrational variables can not be represented by the float or double type. In fact, I would argue that any finite sequence of digits constituting a float has a rational synonym. Even some infinite sequences have this property. Therefore, why not use rationals? It appears to be easier, especially to support larger numbers. Am I being naive here? Why do we need floats over a (partial) rational implementation?

```
#include <iostream>

class Rational
{
public:
    Rational (int numerator, int denominator, int exponent)
    :
        m_numerator(numerator),
        m_denominator(denominator),
        m_exponent(exponent)
    {}

    friend Rational operator* (const Rational &lhs, const Rational &rhs);
    friend std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &os, const Rational &out);

private:

    int m_numerator, m_denominator, m_exponent;
};

Rational operator* (const Rational &lhs, const Rational &rhs)
{
    Rational tmp = lhs;
    tmp.m_numerator *= rhs.m_numerator;
    tmp.m_denominator *= rhs.m_denominator;
    tmp.m_exponent += rhs.m_exponent;
    return tmp;
}

std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &os, const Rational &out)
{
    os << out.m_numerator << "/" << out.m_denominator << "E" << out.m_exponent;
    return os;
}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    Rational a(1, 3, 10), b(4, 7, -5);
    Rational c = a * b;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Edit:

This is merely **an example**. In any real scenario, something like GMP rationals would be applied. These rationals canonicalize the rational to its lowest form.

Comment: If `Rational` suits your need better than `double`, then use it.... nobody's stopping you

Comment: 1) your implementation is lacking a definition of equality. A floating-point equality test takes one cycle on a modern processor. Bear that in mind as you add division after division to your implementation. 2) A couple of normally-harmless multiplications will overflow the `int` type you use everywhere.

Comment: Do you have implementations of square root or the trig functions? If so, how do you deal with the fact that the exact values are irrational for most rational inputs?

Comment: @PascalCuoq I think you can implement an equality test with just two multiplications. `a/b` is equal to `c/d` if, and only if, `ad` is equal to `cb` (making the denominator of each fraction `bd`). That assumes multiplication works without overflow problems.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan … and you need to multiply the numerator of the Rational with the higher exponent by 10 to the difference of exponents before comparing ad and cb. I was thinking of a normalization step before comparison that would avoid overflows.

Comment: Your implementation of rationals has terrifying behaviour if either the numerator or the denominator overflows.

Comment: @PascalCuoq One could make the integers 'bigints'. As for comparison; canonicalization.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Well how are floats represented? Can they truly represent irrational values? I am afraid not, so why not round them to a rational?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm wondering more why rationals aren't used in languages instead of the more common float.

Comment: @BourgondAries: You might find [this](http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/early-language-design-and-development.html) blog post from Guido van Rossum interesting: in it, he explains why he chose to use floats for Python in place of the rationals of ABC.  "Anecdote: I tried to compute my taxes once using ABC. The program, which seemed fairly straightforward, was taking way too long to compute a few simple numbers. Upon investigation it turned out that it was doing arithmetic on numers with thousands of digits of precision, which were to be rounded to guilders and cents for printing."

Comment: @BourgondAries: Are you still wondering after Patricia Shanahan answered your question?  'Cause she gave a damn good answer.

Comment: @tmyklebu I am still wondering yes, see the comment on Patricia's answer.

Comment: @UltimateHawk You might be interested in Bel that Paul Graham posted today. It describes a numeric system based entirely on rationals adjoined with i. https://sep.yimg.com/ty/cdn/paulgraham/bellanguage.txt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three main reasons "why not". If none of them apply, a rational number system may be useful for your application:

1. Compactness. It only takes 8 bytes to store a double, 4 bytes for a float. The is not important if you are dealing with one or two of them. It does matter for matrices with thousands of rows and columns.
2. Performance. As Pascal Cuoq pointed out in a comment on the question, many important floating point operations are very fast on modern computers.
3. Need to approximate irrational numbers such as `pi` and the values of functions such as square root and the trig functions. If you need to deal with rounding anyway, general rational numbers lose a lot of their attraction. Floating point numbers are, of course, rational, but with carefully designed rounding implemented in fast hardware.

If you think your Rational class has usable compactness and performance for scientific and engineering work, I think you should use it to run the [LINPACK benchmarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINPACK_benchmarks), especially LINPACK 1000, and post your results for comparison to results for similar systems using floating point arithmetic. LINPACK 1000 times solving a system of 1000 simultaneous linear equations

Comment: I'd add to your third point that you often also need to approximate *rational* numbers that happen to have unpleasantly large numerators and denominators.  While a question may have an exact rational answer, getting there using exact rational arithmetic can be prohibitively expensive.  Floating-point computation is often a key first step toward getting an exact rational answer should one be desired.

Comment: @tmyklebu I see your point, but thought of that as being covered by points 1 and 2. The objection to using rationals  throughout is generally that they take too much space or take too long to compute.

Comment: It appears I have not researched enough. I am currently (after some research) under the impression that builtin floating point values are actually rationals of the form int/E, where E is the number: 10^-exponent. It appears to be something I am fine with. My question was somewhat misguided. I'll not accept the answer as sufficient since it did not explain that floats are in essence rational. Unless I am wrong and it is explained why they are not so.

Comment: The commonly implemented formats use radix 2, so exact representation of numbers is limited to `a/b` where `a` is an integer, and `b` is an integer power of two, not ten. The point about irrationals is that, even if you can represent any arbitrary rational number, you have to support rounding if you need to approximate irrationals. Most programs that need irrationals are going to work better with that rounding designed by experts and implemented in very fast hardware.

Comment: Would you edit that into the answer for those who might ponder the same question and stumble upon this thread? I think I will then accept your question as the answer.

Comment: Done. Are you going to attempt the Linpack1000 benchmark? By the standards of scientific and engineering programs, it is not a particularly challenging computation.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Perhaps I will, thanks for letting me know about it. I'm currently working on a bigger project and will most likely be benchmarking it after it is done.

Comment: So... the exponent member of your rational suggests that you propose a floating point denominator ?  Or have I misunderstood that ?  Clearly, when multiplying rationals, the numerator and/or denominator can grow quickly, and need scaling back... so you end up with rounding errors in both.  Unless, of course, you set about factorising the results... but I have a feeling that is easier said than done.